# How to get a route param

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

This is how my router looks like:

```
export default new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [

        /**
         * Authentication
         */

        {   name: 'login',
            path: '/',
            component: Login,
            guest: true
        },

        {   name: 'registration',
            path: '/registreer',
            component: Registration,
            guest: true
        },

        /**
         * Forum
         */

        {   name: 'forum',
            path: '/forum',
            component: Forum,
            auth: true
        },
    ]
});
```

Now I would like to get the `auth` value when I go to `/forum`. How do I get that value? I can't find anything in [the docs](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/navigation-guards.html).

Already tried this:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    console.log(to.auth);
    next()
});
```

But nothing show up, only `undefined`.

Any ideas?

Comment: You'll need to iterate over [matched routes](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/meta.html).

Comment: you cannot set keys like you want .. use meta : {auth:true}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good use case for **Vuex** - https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/intro.html

**Vuex** allows you to maintain the state of the application, and also store various API responses so that you do not have to reload the same data in other components.

In your specific case, your `forum` component can check the Vuex state if `auth` is available (this can be done in `created` or `mounted` handler). If `auth` is not available, then you should immediately re-route to auth page using `this.$router.replace("/login")`

In your `auth` component or `login` component, you can do the authentication normally. Once the user login is successful, you can store the server response in `this.$store.state["auth"]` - the Vuex state that is available globally for all components. This can be done as follows (as a mutation in Vuex store):

```js
Vue.set(state, "auth", currentUserDetailsObject)
```

Afterwards, you may redirect to `forum` component, where `auth` is available in `this.$store.state` and therefore forum may proceed to display the component normally.

You may need some ramp-up time to get used to the concepts of `actions` and `mutations`, but you will find it very helpful for the rest of your app, once you get used to it.

Answer (score 0):

- I think you could find what you want [**here**](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/meta.html).
- And you probably want to know about [**Vuex**](http://vuex.vuejs.org/en/state.html).
- Then you can write code like this.

  ```
  if (!store.getters.auth) {
      next({
          path: '/login',
          query: {redirect: to.fullPath}
      })
  }
  ```